# ANGULARJS search in array element and remove corresponding data from the array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I am using angularjs. My json is

```
[
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 1,
      "workflow_id": 1,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 2,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 2,
      "workflow_id": 2,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 3,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 3,
      "workflow_id": 3,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 4,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 4,
      "workflow_id": 5,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  }
]
```

i just want to search whole json is contains or having the node `Workflow_version_id` and `value 2` . if the value is presented the i want to remove the **data** for the same .eg
if  my current `Workflow_version_id is 2` the i want to remove the full details for the id 2

```
{
    "Workflow_version_id": 2,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 2,
      "workflow_id": 2,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  }
```

Then my final json will be like

```
[
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 1,
      "workflow_id": 1,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 3,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 3,
      "workflow_id": 3,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 4,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 4,
      "workflow_id": 5,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can can use `array#filter`.

Comment: @HassanImam i am new in the angular . Can you please give some example to do the same in my case.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PranavMS it is not about AngularJS. This is pure JavaScript approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my **updated answer**. Check it out working code: http://jsfiddle.net/nwa00chg/

```
Array.prototype.removeAt = function(id) {
    for (var item in this) {
        if (this[item].Workflow_version_id == id) {
            this.splice(item, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @PranavMS did you check my answer?

Comment: @VicJordan please im checking your answer.

Comment: @VicJordan man you are awsome.. it is works like a magic.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @PranavMS my pleasure. I am happy that it worked for you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Using filter and hasOwnProperty to check key if it is present is what you need.

```js
var str = [
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 1,
      "workflow_id": 1,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 2,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 2,
      "workflow_id": 2,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 3,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 3,
      "workflow_id": 3,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  },
  {
    "Workflow_version_id": 4,
    "data": {
      "Workflow_version_id": 4,
      "workflow_id": 5,
      "version_number": 1,
      "subversion_number": 1,
      "Workflow_definition": 1,
      "published": true,
      "del_flag": true,
      "locked_on": "asdasd",
      "locked_by": "asasas",
      "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
    }
  }
];

var updatedJson = str.filter(function(data) {
    return data.hasOwnProperty("Workflow_version_id");

})
console.log(updatedJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using simple JavaScript.

> Assume var data = [] //array of your object.

```
var index = data.findIndex(function(o){ return o.Workflow_version_id == 2});
```

variable index will have the index of object.

> Remove the object from index

```
data.splice(index,1) //after that data object will not have that object.
```

If array does not have unique Id then you can use array#filter which will remove all the element which satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check with this. Hope this will help

```
$scope.Data.myData=[
{
"Workflow_version_id": 1,
"data": {
  "Workflow_version_id": 1,
  "workflow_id": 1,
  "version_number": 1,
  "subversion_number": 1,
  "Workflow_definition": 1,
  "published": true,
  "del_flag": true,
  "locked_on": "asdasd",
  "locked_by": "asasas",
  "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
}
},
{
"Workflow_version_id": 2,
"data": {
  "Workflow_version_id": 2,
  "workflow_id": 2,
  "version_number": 1,
  "subversion_number": 1,
  "Workflow_definition": 1,
  "published": true,
  "del_flag": true,
  "locked_on": "asdasd",
  "locked_by": "asasas",
  "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
}
},
{
"Workflow_version_id": 3,
"data": {
  "Workflow_version_id": 3,
  "workflow_id": 3,
  "version_number": 1,
  "subversion_number": 1,
  "Workflow_definition": 1,
  "published": true,
  "del_flag": true,
  "locked_on": "asdasd",
  "locked_by": "asasas",
  "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
}
},
{
"Workflow_version_id": 4,
"data": {
  "Workflow_version_id": 4,
  "workflow_id": 5,
  "version_number": 1,
  "subversion_number": 1,
  "Workflow_definition": 1,
  "published": true,
  "del_flag": true,
  "locked_on": "asdasd",
  "locked_by": "asasas",
  "version_comments": "ASasaaaa"
}
}
]
 $scope.filterData = function (SourceArray, SourceColumnname, searchValue) {
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < SourceArray.length; i++) {
        if (SourceArray[i][SourceColumnname] == searchValue) {
            tempArray.push(SourceArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
};
var filteredData= $scope.filterData($scope.Data.myData, "Workflow_version_id", 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array#filter` and compare the `Workflow_version_id` with the value you want to remove.

```js
var data = [ { "Workflow_version_id": 1, "data": { "Workflow_version_id": 1, "workflow_id": 1, "version_number": 1, "subversion_number": 1, "Workflow_definition": 1, "published": true, "del_flag": true, "locked_on": "asdasd", "locked_by": "asasas", "version_comments":"ASasaaaa" } }, { "Workflow_version_id": 2, "data": { "Workflow_version_id": 2, "workflow_id": 2, "version_number": 1, "subversion_number": 1, "Workflow_definition": 1, "published": true, "del_flag": true, "locked_on": "asdasd", "locked_by": "asasas","version_comments": "ASasaaaa" } }, { "Workflow_version_id": 3, "data": { "Workflow_version_id": 3, "workflow_id": 3, "version_number": 1, "subversion_number": 1, "Workflow_definition": 1, "published": true, "del_flag": true, "locked_on": "asdasd", "locked_by":"asasas", "version_comments": "ASasaaaa" } }, { "Workflow_version_id": 4, "data": { "Workflow_version_id": 4, "workflow_id": 5, "version_number": 1, "subversion_number": 1, "Workflow_definition": 1, "published": true, "del_flag": true, "locked_on": "asdasd",
"locked_by": "asasas", "version_comments": "ASasaaaa" } } ];
data = data.filter(o => o.Workflow_version_id !== 2);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: If OP doesn't have duplicate `Workflow_version_id` among objects, this is the correct approach. It he has, then this approach is quite inefficient as it will traverse the entire array.

Comment: @NegiRox IE 9 and above support array filter and you can use polyfill to support old version.

Comment: @31piy I find `array#filter` to be useful when removing object instead of `array#splice`, also, `array#filter` will remove all the occurrences.

Comment: @HassanImam -- I could have agreed, but the statement that _`array#filter` is useful_ is not completely right. I think this is usecase-specific. There is nothing wrong with array#splice, and removing one element by index is far more efficient than traversing the entire array, leaving behind the unwanted elements.

Comment: Well, I meant, when one wants to remove multiple values.

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility)